# Wrong boundary when plotting Canada's shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, canada, borders

I want to plot the Canadian shapefile with province boundaries highlighted and hollow filling.

I have downloaded the shapefile from [here](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=gpr_000a11a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%20%202194&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gpr_000a11a_e.zip).

This is the script I use to visualize the shapefile:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
#   -- input --
sf = shapefile.Reader("myfolder\gpr_000a11a_e.shp")
recs    = sf.records()
shapes  = sf.shapes()
Nshp    = len(shapes)
cns     = []
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    cns.append(recs[nshp][1])
cns = array(cns)
cm    = get_cmap('Dark2')
cccol = cm(1.*arange(Nshp)/Nshp)
#   -- plot --
fig     = plt.figure()
ax      = fig.add_subplot(111)
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    ptchs   = []
    pts     = array(shapes[nshp].points)
    prt     = shapes[nshp].parts
    par     = list(prt) + [pts.shape[0]]
    for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
     ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]]))
    ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs,facecolor=cccol[nshp,:],edgecolor='k', linewidths=.1))
ax.set_xlim(-160,-40)
ax.set_ylim(40,90)
```

The output is confusing, in that the Northern border is completely wrong and it does not resemble the real one. I think there are unwanted lines that connect points far away from each other. As a result, the islands in Northern Nunavut have been merged in a single polygon. **How to obtain a neat border?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polygon is not "wrong", it's just not representing landmass [image]

It uses 1 polygon for each province.

You can find polygons representing Canada's borders and land surface on [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) or [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata)

Comment: And do you know where I can get a shapefile representing the true landmass?

Comment: @CF84 I've just edited my answer, take a look at the links. you can always do a search for "Canada District Shapefile" and find plenty of results as well